# Dig DNS ,sometime get right answer , sometime get wrong answer

Tags: dns, nameservers, dig

After update the nameserver of my dns which in Godaddy, I dig the DNS's NS , sometime get right answer, sometime get wrong answer

```
dig +short NS licloud.greenvalleyintl.com
```

sometime get nothing

sometime get:

```
ns-676.awsdns-20.net.
ns-1134.awsdns-13.org.
ns-2007.awsdns-58.co.uk.
ns-242.awsdns-30.com.
```

and if I use curl command, sometime return

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: licloud.greenvalleyintl.com
```

sometime return the right info

Comment: Always use dig with `@` to clearly specify which nameserver you query. Also use online troubleshooting tools: https://zonemaster.net/ and https://dnsviz.net/

Answer (score 0):

Some of the nameservers that you are claiming will serve your zone aren't serving it. This includes LYNN.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM, and VAL.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM. Most likely, you need to go to your registrar's control panel for your domain and remove them.